# Dataframes saved to S3/S3A from Spark are unencrypted despite settings "fs.s3a.encryption.algorithm" and "fs.s3a.encryption.key"

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, encryption, pyspark

#### Description

Within PySpark, even though a DataFrame can be saved to S3/S3A (not AWS, but a S3-compliant storage), its data are saved unencrypted despite that setting `fs.s3a.encryption.algorithm` (`SSE-C`) and `fs.s3a.encryption.key` are used.

#### Reproducibility

Generate the key as followed:

```
encKey=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
```

Start PySpark shell:

```
pyspark --master spark://[some_host]:7077 \
    --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.0.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.901,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1 \
    --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
    --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

Within PySpark, a toy example:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "[access.key]")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "[secret.key]")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "[s3.compliant.endpoint]")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.encryption.algorithm", "SSE-C")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.encryption.key", "[the_encKey_above]")

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)

#df.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("s3a://data/test")

df.repartition(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("s3a://data/test")
```

We can see the folder `s3a://data/test` created, and there is a CSV file in there. But unfortunately, the file is **not encrypted**. That said, it can be even downloaded manually through web browser and then viewed with notepad! The setting `fs.s3a.encryption.algorithm` seems to be ignored.

#### Environment

- Apache Spark v3.2.2
- Hadoop-aws v3.3.1 / Hadoop-common v3.3.1
- openjdk 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12 (Temurin)
- Python 3.10.4
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

#### Debug

Interestingly, the same endpoint has no problem with encrypting the uploaded file, if using AWS CLI:

```
aws --endpoint-url https://[s3.compliant.endpoint] \
    s3api put-object \
    --body "/home/[a_user]/Desktop/a_file.csv" \
    --bucket "data" \
    --key "test/a_file.csv" \
    --sse-customer-algorithm AES256 \
    --sse-customer-key $encKey \
    --sse-customer-key-md5 $md5Key
```

```
aws -version
# aws-cli/2.7.35 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.15.0-48-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off
```

I read the manual guide [Working with Encrypted S3 Data](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/encryption.html), but no help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

The libraries `hadoop-aws v3.3.1` / `aws-java-sdk-bundle v1.11.901` / `hadoop-common v3.3.1` must have some bugs, or be simply incompatible with the S3's latest protocol (as of 2022.10.06). The aforementioned issue can be overcome by using the latest versions of the libraries, meaning: `hadoop-aws v3.3.4` (thus, `aws-java-sdk-bundle v1.12.262` dependency), and `hadoop-common v3.3.4` (to match the `hadoop-aws`).

Among the release notes from 3.3.2 to 3.3.4, there may be some fixes related to AWS/S3 that help overcome the issue.

- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/release/3.3.2/CHANGELOG.3.3.2.html
- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/release/3.3.3/CHANGELOG.3.3.3.html
- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/release/3.3.4/CHANGELOG.3.3.4.html

Summarily, for PySpark, use:

```
pyspark --master spark://[some_host]:7077 \
    --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.0.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.262,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.4 \
    --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
    ...
```

Comment: that's a bit of a harsh accusation given that (a) aws doesn't do incompatible protocol changes and (b) we have lots of regression tests for things like encryption in the hadoop-aws test module. "using docs out of sync with binaries" is the cause here. i would downgrade the response except that using the most recent version of the hadoop binaries  is always best.

Answer (score 0):

When using hadoop 3.3.1 or earlier, use fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm and  "fs.s3a.server-side-encryption.key"; the  "fs.s3a.encryption.*" options only came in hadoop 3.3.2 and support for client side encryption in HADOOP-13887